# Emulating JavaScript's bitwise shift behavior

Tags: javascript

I somewhat understand JS uses floating point numbers and casts them as integers when doing a shift, thus resulting in different values than in other languages:

```
1801876324 << 25
```

That outputs `-939524096` in JS but a far longer value in other languages (`147634913777578...`)

How can I emulate JS's behavior?

Comment: In what other languages?

Comment: I know Ruby for sure, PHP & Java I believe. I *think* this is related to JS doing 32 bits only and the others 64 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite correct in your thinking.

Consider:
hex(1801876324) == 0x6b667364

hex(1801876324 << 25) == 0xd6cce6c8000000

After truncation to 32 bits the eventual value will be 0xc8000000, which happens to equal -939524096 in two's complement arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting number mean's Just multiply or divide by 2^numbits like.

`for(i=0;i<numdigit;i++) largeNum = largeNum*2`

> or

`for(i=0;i<numdigit;i++) largeNum = largeNum/2`